# Get the value of NodeType and add some class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My issue is that I've got a div with any integer, and I want to replace it for a span for every number.

Here you are my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/christianMM/qns7ohx2/

My html code is:

```
<div class="precios price2">99,99</div>
```

My JS code is:

```
$(function () { 
    function wrapCharacters() {
        $('.precios').contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === 1) {
                wrapCharacters(this);
            } else if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.nodeValue.split(''), function (c) {
                    return '<span class="big p' + c + '">' + c + '</span>';
                }).join(''));
            }
        });
    }
    wrapCharacters($('.precios'));
});
```

Thats's working now, but I can't get the value of **c.NodeValue**. 'Cause I need to change the value of ',' to 'comma', to add this class to my div.

Somebody can help me which one is the best way to get it?

Thnaks a lot,
Luiggi

Comment: Why are you passing arguments to the function and then absolutely not using them anywhere?

Comment: `c` is a single character string. It does not have a `.NodeValue` property. What do you want to do?

Comment: Why `c.NodeValue`, `c` is the value itself

Comment: Finally ad this:  if (c == ',') {
        c='-comma';
       return '<span class="big p' + c +'">' + c + '</span>';
       }else{
       return '<span class="big p' + c +'">' + c + '</span>';

       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally ad some IF to my JS code to detect my comma, and add "-comma" class to the :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function wrapCharacters() {
        $('.precios').contents().each(function() {
            if(this.nodeType === 1) {
                wrapCharacters(this);
            }
            else if(this.nodeType === 3) {
                $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.nodeValue.split(''), function(c) {

                    if (c == ',') {
                        c='-comma';
                    return '<span class="big p' + c +'">' + c + '</span>';
                    }else{
                    return '<span class="big p' + c +'">' + c + '</span>';

                    }
                }).join(''));
            }
        });
    }    


    wrapCharacters($('.precios'));
});
```